# Share Google Drive folder without sending notification

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to automate a process for sharing Drive folders with certain people of interest. The emails of those people are collected by a Google Forms and can be easily recovered. I first added them as 'readers' using `.addViewer()` however it sends the notification email, which I don't want.

However when I try this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var solicitud=ss.getSheetByName("Respuestas de formulario 1");
  
  var ultimaFila=solicitud.getLastRow()
  
  var colegio=solicitud.getRange(ultimaFila,3).getValue();
  var responsable=solicitud.getRange(ultimaFila,6).getValue();
  var consultor=solicitud.getRange(ultimaFila,2).getValue();
  var fecha=solicitud.getRange(ultimaFila,11).getValue();
  
  var destFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById("1MqMVDEnCbeWci5RiS9WZTZx1YSkhdVJt");
  
  var newFolder=destFolder.createFolder(colegio);
  
  //Cómo compartir sin manadr notificación. Tiene que ver con Servicios Avanzados:
  var request = Drive.Permissions.insert(
   {
     'role': 'reader',
     'type': 'user',
     'value': 'consultor'
   },
   newFolder,
   {
     'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'
   });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If possible can you translate the comment and non english variables? It will help people understand the code better

Comment: Hello @PavlinPetkov thankyou for pointing that out! I will take your suggestion and have decided just to write always in english in the future. The project in itself is for my work, where colleagues speak spanish. First post here and didn't cross my mind. Again, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues in your `Drive.Permissions.insert()` call:

1. The [`value` property](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions#value) should be an email address. Right now you're passing the string `'consultor'` rather than the value in the variable, which I'm assuming is the email address.
2. Instead of passing `newFolder`, you need to pass the [ID of the folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getid). You can see this in one of Google's examples [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive#adding_custom_properties).
3. (Optional) The `sendNotificationEmails` should be the boolean `false`, not the string `'false'`. It should work either way, but it's always best to use the correct type.

```
var request = Drive.Permissions.insert(
  {
    'role': 'reader',
    'type': 'user',
    'value': consultor // This should be an email address
  },
  newFolder.getId(),
  {
    'sendNotificationEmails': false
  }
);
```

Also, best practices state that you should use [batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations). In your script, you call `getRange()` four times. This works, but you could make it run a little bit faster if you get the entire row values once and then select the individual values from the array.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var solicitud=ss.getSheetByName("Respuestas de formulario 1");

  var ultimaFila=solicitud.getLastRow();
  var datos=solicitud.getRange(ultimaFila, 1, 1).getValues(); // Get all of the data in the final row once
  var colegio=datos[0][2]; // Column 3
  var responsable=datos[0][5]; // Column 6
  var consultor=datos[0][1]; // Column 2
  var fecha=datos[0][10]; // Column 11

  var destFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById("1MqMVDEnCbeWci5RiS9WZTZx1YSkhdVJt");

  var newFolder=destFolder.createFolder(colegio);

  //Cómo compartir sin manadr notificación. Tiene que ver con Servicios Avanzados:
  var request = Drive.Permissions.insert(
    {
      role: 'reader',
      type: 'user',
      value: consultor
    },
    newFolder.getId(),
    {
      sendNotificationEmails: false
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Wow, thankyou for your detailed feedback. I got it working:

Answer (score 0):

thankyou both for your quick responses. Here is the final product (everything in english as well). I was even able to loop adding permissions as I actually needed two people as readers:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var solicitud=ss.getSheetByName("Respuestas de formulario 1");
  var lastRow = solicitud.getLastRow()
  var data = solicitud.getRange(lastRow,1,lastRow,13).getValues();
  var school = data[0][2]
  var contact = data[0][5];
  var consultant = data[0][1];
  var date = data[0][10];
  var destFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById("1FYm5OIKfes4GWsc7w8KYm4IsXLheMAu2");
  var newFolder=destFolder.createFolder(school);
  var persons = [consultant, contact]
  
  Logger.log(data)
  Logger.log(consultant)
  
  //How to share a folder silently, with drive notification email:
  
  for (var i=0; i<persons.length; i++){
  Drive.Permissions.insert(
   {
     'role': 'reader',
     'type': 'user',
     'value': persons[i]
   },
   newFolder.getId(),
   {
     'sendNotificationEmails': false
   }
  );
  }
    
  var newFolderId=newFolder.getId();
  solicitud.getRange(lastRow,14).setValue("https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/" + newFolderId);
 
  
  // Make a copy of the form, in the newly created folder with school name. Get id of form and open file.
  
  var newForm = DriveApp.getFileById('1Ax8EfVrpxbez_plZHwDEiuOJM9cPN-XNOJ53OqyY6Vc').makeCopy("Evaluación Previa" + "_" + school + "_" + date, newFolder);
  var newFormId = newForm.getId();
  var newFormOpen = FormApp.openById(newFormId);
  
  
  // Make a copy of a decoy sheet, setting same name as form, in same destination folder, then link new form to new sheet.
  var newSheet = DriveApp.getFileById('1K_QuWNa4OPjlC0S3R76XBILQkqd6kh54hRcXVqruVto').makeCopy("Evaluación Previa_" + school + "_" + date, newFolder);
  var newSheetId = newSheet.getId();
  newFormOpen.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, newSheet.getId());  
 
  var newFormPublished = newFormOpen.getPublishedUrl();
  var newSheetUrl = newSheet.getUrl()
```